# how to change date timezone in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, date, express, mongoose

In model schema,

Using

```
updated: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
```

In server.js

```
put(function(req, res) {
    var query = {name: req.params.name};
    // use our bear model to find the bear we want
    Domain.find(query, function(err, domains) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);
        var domain = domains[0];
        domain.password = req.body.password;  // update the bears info
        domain.updated = new Date();
        // save the bear
        domain.save(function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ status: 'success', message: 'domain updated!' }, data);
        });

    });
});
```

However,

In db side it shows,

```
"updated": "2016-02-27T16:20:42.941Z"
```

But, my timezone is UTC+02.00

So it should be like 18:20:42

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm using moment-timezone

```
npm install moment-timezone

const moment = require('moment-timezone');
const dateThailand = moment.tz(Date.now(), "Asia/Bangkok");

console.log(dateThailand); // "2018-08-20T16:35:14.033+07:00"
*** Asia/Bangkok +07:00
```

Schema in the mongoose.

```
const categorySchema = new Schema(
    {
        _id: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, auto: true},
        c_name: String,
        created_by: String,
        created_date: {type: Date, default: dateThailand},
        updated_by: String,
        updated_date: {type: Date, default: dateThailand}
    }, {_id: false}
);
```

See up that `created_date, updated_date: {type: Date, default: dateThailand }`

*Read more:* http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

***If you using Robo 3T tool.**

You can set "Display Dates In..."

```
Options > Display Dates In... > Local Timezone
```

[image]

:) Work for me.

Comment: when you query dates, do you still get the dates in the timezone that you specified or mongodb returns dates in UTC format

Answer (score 7):

The timestamps are timezone agnostic, stored as a unix timestamp. This timestamp will work across timezones, and node interprets it using current timezone of the server. The date you've shown is correctly stored. As soon as you'll retrieve it, if your server's timezone is UTC+2, it will show you correct time.

Comment: my ubuntu server timezone is EET so do I need to change it to UTC+2?

Comment: Best practice would be to keep your server's timezone to UTC, so that you do not get frustrated over datetime difference queries. Date-time will be much easier to reason about when in UTC. I've done it a lot of times and it saves you from a lot of time zone conversion headaches.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing wrong in your code. MongoDb saves date in UTC format no matter in whichever timezone you try to insert your date.

If you log domain.updated before saving in DB, result will be UTC+2 (your local time)

If you see updated column in DB, result will be in UTC

If you fetch updated column value from DB, then again result will be in UTC+2 (your local time)

Comment: So, how can I solve this ? Console.log is giving correct time but after insertion different time is shown their !

Answer (score 3):

I changed this,

```
var utc = new Date();
utc.setHours( utc.getHours() + 2);
domain.updated = utc;
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Date Object from a specific UTC time:

```js
new Date(Date.UTC(year, month, day, hour, minute, second))
```

Answer (score 2):

Remember that no matter what you use to set time in mongoose schema, mongoose will always use UTC time, hence you need to dynamically allocate the UTC timestamp inside the Schema. Here it goes :-

```
var current = new Date();
const timeStamp = new Date(Date.UTC(current.getFullYear(), 
current.getMonth(),current.getDate(),current.getHours(), 
current.getMinutes(),current.getSeconds(), current.getMilliseconds()));

//Here goes your schema 
const auditSchema = mongoose.Schema({
           dateTime : { type: Date, default : timeStamp }
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. No need to install anything else too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using [`moment.js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) it is as easy as:

```
var moment = require('moment');

var utcDate = moment.utc().toDate();
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this for IST:

```
const companySchema = new Schema({
    name : { type: String, default : "" },
    email : { type: String, default : "" }
},
{ 
    timestamps: { currentTime: () => {
        let date = new Date();
        let newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000 * -1));
        return newDate;
    }},  
    versionKey: false 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple I have found another way to fix this problem doesn't matter UTC just add two line in mongoose...

```
const time = new Date();
const currentDate =
time.toLocaleDateString() + " " + time.toLocaleTimeString();
```

And during post request just send this `currentDate` in schema and it will save time as your region