# Mongoose datetime and timezone, how to get datetime based on server timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongoose, timezone

The first answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672248/how-to-change-date-timezone-in-mongoose) question suggests that mongoose would adapt the date according to server timezone when retrieving data.

However, I don't have this comportement.
I set the (node) server timezone with :
`process.env.TZ='Europe/Paris'`

For exemple if I create a simple model like :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    myDate: { type: Date, required: true },
}, { timestamps: true });

exports.Comment = mongoose.default.model('TestSchema', testSchema);
```

But if I create a date with `2020-01-01 20:20:20`, when doing `TestSchema.find()` the date will be: `2020-01-01T19:20:20.000Z` so there are two things that I don't understand :

- Europe/Paris is actually UTC +2, so I would expect the date to be either  `2020-01-01T18:20:20.000Z` in UTC or `2020-01-01T20:20:20.000Z` with the server timezone
- How to have mongoose automatically set the date to the correct timezone?

I know that `myDate` is a Date object, so I can convert it manually but I'd rather not have to do it myself for simple reasons like forgetting to convert one of the dates in the application or not having to do it every time a `Date` field is added

An easy solution that I can think of would be to register a global plugin for mongoose which would use `schema.set('toJSON', ...` and `schema.set('toObject', ...)` with the transform method so I can loop through schema fields and if the field is a Date, update it to my timezone.
But I see two problems with this approch :

- It doesn't sound very good performance-wise if I am querying a lot of documents each with a lot of fields
- As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55725534/cannot-register-mongoose-global-plugin) I am currently not able to register global plugins...

What would be the best method to get the date in the server timezone format? I would rather still store them in UTC but set the hour according to the server timezone.

EDIT :

I just saw that while `console.log(myDate)` outputs `2018-01-01T19:20:20.000Z` `console.log(myDate.toString()` outputs `Mon Jan 01 2018 20:20:20 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)` so it seems likes this could be used, even tho I'd rather still have a `Date` object and converting it to string just before sending it to the client (would need some formatting tho since this format is not very user friendly). But then again, how would I do this globally and not for every date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- `Europe/Paris` at `2020-01-01T20:20:20` is UTC+1.  It doesn't switch to UTC+2 until Summer Time kicks in on March 29th.  [Reference here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/france/paris).  Thus the conversion to `2020-01-01T19:20:20Z` is correct.
- The output of `console.log` when passed a `Date` object is implementation specific.  Some implementations will emit the output of `.toString()` (which is in local time in [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.3) format), and some will emit the output of `.toISOString()` (which is in UTC in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) extended format).  That is why you see the difference.
- In general, it is not good to send a local time without also sending a time zone offset.  ISO 8601 format is ideal, but you should send either `2020-01-01T19:20:20Z`, or `2020-01-01T20:20:20+01:00`.  Don't just send the date and time without an offset to the client.  Otherwise, if your client could be in a different time zone then they would interpret the value incorrectly.
- Keep in mind that `Date` objects are *not* time zone aware.  They contain only a Unix timestamp internally, and they convert only to the system's local time zone for the functions that work in local time.  They cannot work in any other time zone.
- Relying on the system local time zone is bad for portability.  One doesn't always have the ability to change it, and it doesn't do well when you have to work in multiple time zones.  It would be better to *not* rely on setting a local time zone from Node's `TZ` variable.  Instead, consider writing your code to be independent of any local time zone setting.
- A time zone aware date library can help with most of your concerns.  I can recommend [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), [js-Joda](https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/), [Moment](http://momentjs.com/) + [Moment-Timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/), or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) + [date-fns-timezone](https://date-fns.org/).
- "how would I do this globally" is something I'm not following in your question.  Try the approach I described, and if you still have issues then open a new question.  Try to be specific and ask a *single* question.  You're likely to get better results that way.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Thanks.

Comment: Very interesting. The more I read about date and timezone the more complex this subject is. Keep in mind this a school project however I'd like to follow the best practices If I am understanding your answer well, I should send UTC dates to the client and the client should adapt it before showing it ? I do apologize for the last point, seems likes "how would I do this globally" is just not a good question for this site

Comment: So the whole logic to convert date based on user timezone should be done client side. Seems pretty logic tho. And your point about sending date + timezone is excellent

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue:

```
npm i mongoose-timezone
```

In your schema file:

```
import timeZone from "mongoose-timezone";

const testSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    myDate: { type: Date, required: true },
}, { timestamps: true });

// mongoose will save the dates based on user's timezone
testSchema.plugin(timeZone)
```

> mongoose-timezone basically adds the current timezone offset to the
> date before store and removes the offset when retrieving data. This
> way dates are kept proportional in the database and in the app.