# how to get the current time zone in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i'm trying to get the currrent time in mongodb but it keeps returning an hour late this is my schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VisitSchema = new Schema({
    ipAddress: String,
    userAgent: String,
    url: String,
    time: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },


);

const Visit = mongoose.model("Visit", VisitSchema);
module.exports = Visit;
```

the time keeps returning an hour late ahead of my current time , please how do i get the exact time

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672248/how-to-change-date-timezone-in-mongoose

Answer (score 0):

first you install **`moment-timezone library`** by running **`npm install moment-timezone`** before using it in your code.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const moment = require("moment-timezone");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const VisitSchema = new Schema({
  ipAddress: String,
  userAgent: String,
  url: String,
  time: { type: Date, default: () => moment().tz("Your Time Zone").toDate() },
  count: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});

const Visit = mongoose.model("Visit", VisitSchema);
module.exports = Visit;
```

**time** field using **() => moment().tz("Your Time Zone").toDate(),** it will generate the current date and time adjusted to the specified time zone.

Replace "**Your Time Zone**" with the appropriate value for your time zone, such as "America/New_York" or "Europe/London". You can find a list of valid time zone values in the [click](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-formats/packed-format/)

hope it's helps

Comment: I think you can simply use `moment().toDate` because moment uses by default the current local time zone.